# Multidimensional array wont update ( C++ )

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, multidimensional-array

I implemented Bellman-Kalaba's algorithm for finding the greatest value of the roads from vertex 1 to any other, in an graph. 
The problem is( silly though ), the second bidimensional array ***matriceaDrumurilorMaxime[20][20]*** passed as argument in the function **wont change any value**, even though I do assign values to it, or from the other one to this. I do initialize the first array ***matriceaValorilor[20][20]*** from file, and it works fine. The second array is just initialized to 0, as u can see in main function. I use Visual Studio 2012, maybe it is an IDE problem ? Maybe someone also had this problem and can help me a bit...

```
void bellmanKalaba(int matriceaValorilor[20][20], int dim, int matriceaDrumurilorMaxime[20][20], int &linii, int &coloane)
{
    linii = 1;
    coloane = dim;
    for(int j = 0; j < dim; j++)
    {
        matriceaDrumurilorMaxime[0][j] = matriceaValorilor[j][dim-1];
    }

    bool sfarsit = false;
    while(sfarsit != true)
    {   
        for(int poz = 0; poz < coloane; poz++)
        {
            int valMax = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < coloane; j++)
            {
                if( matriceaDrumurilorMaxime[linii-1][j] + matriceaValorilor[poz][j] > valMax )
                    valMax = matriceaDrumurilorMaxime[linii-1][j] + matriceaValorilor[poz][j];
            }
            matriceaDrumurilorMaxime[linii][poz] = valMax;
        }
        sfarsit = true;
        int k = 0;
        while(sfarsit == true)
        {
            if(matriceaDrumurilorMaxime[linii][k] != matriceaDrumurilorMaxime[linii-1][k])
                sfarsit = false;
            ++k;
        }
        ++linii;
    }
}

void citireMatriceaValorilorDinFisier(int matriceaValorilor[20][20], int &dimensiune, char* numefisier)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    dimensiune = 0;
    ifstream file(numefisier);
    string line;
    string element;
    size_t pos = 0;
    string delimiter = " ";

    while(getline(file,line))
    {
        ++dimensiune;
        while(pos = line.find(delimiter, 0) != string::npos)
        {
            pos = line.find(delimiter, 0);
            element = line.substr(0,pos);
            matriceaValorilor[i][j] = atoi(element.c_str());
            line.erase(0, pos+delimiter.length());
            ++j;
        }
        ++i;
        j = 0;
    }
    file.close();
}

int main()
{
    cout << "===Problema ordonantarii: graful potentiale etape===" << endl << endl << endl;
    int varfuri = 0;
    int matriceValorilor[20][20] = {0};
    citireMatriceaValorilorDinFisier( matriceValorilor, varfuri, "Graf.txt");
    cout << "Matricea valorilor arcelor:" << endl;
    afisareMatrice( matriceValorilor, varfuri, varfuri );

    int linii, coloane;
    int matriceaDrumurilorMaxime[20][20] = {0};

    bellmanKalaba(matriceValorilor, varfuri, matriceaDrumurilorMaxime, linii, coloane);
    cout << "Matricea valorilor maxime ale drumurilor de la varful 1 la celelalte varfuri:" << endl;
    afisareMatrice( matriceaDrumurilorMaxime, linii, coloane );

    //int dimensiune;
    //int drumMax[20];
    //puncteCritie(matriceaDrumurilorMaxime, varfuri, matriceaDrumurilorMaxime, linii, coloane, drumMax, dimensiune);
    //cout << "Punctele critice ale grafului potentiale etape:" << endl;
    //afisareVector(drumMax, dimensiune);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: OP said in comments on a now-deleted answer that he'd checked in the debugger that `dim` was `4` inside the start of `bellmanKabala()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your main problem or not, but there is a logic error in `bellmanKabala`.

The loop starting `while(sfarsit != true)` can never complete.  This is because it contains the loop starting `while(sfarsit==true)` . Ths inner loop runs until `sfarsit = false` is set. But that means that the outer loop will run again, and there are no other `break` statements or anything.

Eventually `linii` will overflow the bounds of the array and cause undefined behaviour.

As well as fixing this error, you could add in a check after `++linii` that `if (linii >= dim)` then abort and print an error message that something has gone wrong; instead of just overflowing buffer. The inner loop should also check that `k < dim`.

Comment: You are right with the loop! Thank you very much sir! I changed it with an for and a break. The problem with the arrays got solved because of that, strange... :) Now i have another problem on another function, if i dont get it work, should i make a separate post for that, or i can update here? I am new to stackoverflow :D

Comment: Separate post is probably a better idea